# How to find error with segmentation fault

Tags: c

I have a small piece of code, compiled well. But it appears segmentation fault at runtime.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct ListElmt_ // Define a structure for linked list elements. 
{
    void *data;    
    struct ListElmt_  *next;
} ListElmt;


typedef struct List_ //define a structure for linked lists. 
{
    int size; //  the size of the linked list

    ListElmt *head; // the head element
    ListElmt *tail; // the tail elemtent

} List;

void list_init(List *l)
{
    l->size = 0;
    l->head = NULL;     
    l->tail = NULL;
}

int main()
{
    List *ls = NULL;
    list_init(ls);

    return 0;

}
```

I have tried but could not find out what's wrong. Please help? I am a newbie, could anyone suggest me tools to find this kind of error?

Comment: You can't have tried to `debug` too hard. I can see a write to NULL pointer without even trying!

Comment: `List *ls = NULL;
    list_init(ls);` => `l->size = 0;` => `NULL->size = 0;`

Comment: "could anyone suggest me tools to find this kind of error". Debugger.

Comment: But debugger just say **segmentation fault**, It does not show where

Comment: @user271755 Which debugger - gdb? In gdb you should make sure your program is compiled with the `-g` option, and then typing `bt` in the debugger will give you a stack trace (showing where the crash happened, which function called that, which function called that, and so on) including line numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Your failing line is:

```
 l->size = 0;
```

Since you initialized `ls` to `NULL` the above line is doing `NULL->size`, i.e. an illegal dereference. You need to allocate memory for `ls` first.

However, there is no reason for a dynamic allocated `List`. Simply do:

```
int main()
{
    List ls;        // Don't make list a pointer - just an ordinary var
    list_init(&ls); // Pass the address of ls (i.e. &ls) as the function
                    // expects a pointer.

    return 0;    
}
```

To find the kind of problem, you had with the pointer version, you could use a debugger and use single-step, i.e. execute the code line-by-line until you hit the failing point. Another way is to insert a number of `printf` statements so that you can see what the code did just before crashing.

Answer (score 1):

The variable `ls` should be provided memory location before any access.

Use: `ls = malloc(sizeof(List));` before use of `ls`.

A segmentation fault usually appears when trying to access a memory location which does not exist yet.

Comment: Shouldn't this be `List *ls = malloc(sizeof(List));` i.e. `sizeof(List)` not `sizeof(List *)` as you need to allocate the actual data and point to that, not a pointer to a pointer.

Comment: yes, I think you are right. I just amended the answer.